# error for boot-repair : use this software in a live-session (live-CD or live-USB)

Tags: grub2, boot-repair

I'm trying to dual boot my system by Windows 10 and Ubuntu 19.10 .
When I'm trying to install Ubuntu, the installer crashes on installing GRUB2 so my system faces with boot problems.

Now although I'm trying to repair GRUB problems with `boot-repair` on an Ubuntu Live OS, it returns an error :

```
Please use this software in a live-session (live-CD or live-USB). This will enable this feature.
```

What should I do?

Comment: This may not be your issue, but did you verify your downloaded ISO (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0) and then your write to install media (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck)  Failures to install grub can occur; but validating your install media would be my first check.

Comment: The issue also occurred when I tested ubuntu 17.10 iso image that i had installed it before without any problem. So I think it is not my new iso image's problem! And also I'm using a live-USB

Comment: Are you booting in correct boot mode. Since new Windows systems are UEFI if pre-installed and might be BIOS if an upgrade from Windows 7, you need to boot live installer in same boot mode. Your UEFI boot menu should have two entries for booting live installer if Secure Boot is off & allow USB boot is on. Shows installer with screen shots. Both BIOS purple accessibility screen & UEFI black grub menu screen
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Ubuntu 19.10 live usb, grub-repair didn't detect it was run from a live-usb.
My computer uses UEFI. At doc ubuntu website, they advise to run this command in Windows 10, with an admin cmd terminal :

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

It fixed my dual-boot problem